# Why does turtlebot3_teleop behave differently on Windows and Linux?

Tags: ros, turtlebot3, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ROS Noetic installed on a Windows 10 PC and a Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) PC, both with the `turtlebot3_teleop` package.

On Windows 10, when I run

`roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch`

and echo the `/cmd_vel` topic using `rostopic echo /cmd_vel`, I see no messages. When I press a key, say `w`, to send out a Twist command, I see a single message:

```
linear: 
  x: 0.005
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
```

On Linux, as soon as I run the `roslaunch` command, the message

```
linear: 
  x: 0.005
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
```

is repeatedly echoed at around 10 Hz. When I press a key, say `w`, to send out a Twist command, I see the message

```
linear: 
  x: 0.005
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
```

also repeated at around 10 Hz.

Why does the node behave differently on the different operating systems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394355/why-does-turtlebot3_teleop-behave-differently-on-windows-and-linux?/) by [rushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/91378/rushik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-01-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-14**:
Hi @rushik, can you please explain what installation did you use for Windows 10? Also are you comparing simulations or working with the actual turtlebot3? Finally can you show the steps for launching teleop for Windows10?

**Comment by [rushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/91378/rushik/) on 2022-01-15**:
Hi @osilva, I am using the ROS Noetic installation instructions from [this ROS Wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows). I am installing Turtlebot3 packages on my Windows 10 PC using the Windows section of [this page on the Robotis e-Manual](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/).

I am neither simulating the robot, nor working with the actual robot. I am simply comparing what the `turtlebot3_teleop_key` node publishes on the `cmd_vel` topic.

I start the node using `roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch`. I then listen to what it is publishing using `rostopic echo /cmd_vel`.

The only two nodes running are `turtlebot3_teleop_key` and the ROS master. My problem is that on Windows, the `turtlebot3_teleop_key` node publishes a single message per key press. On Linux, it repeats the messages at 10Hz. I need the Windows behavior to match the Linux behavior.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-15**:
Thank you @rushik for all these details. I will reproduce this test and see if I can find something and report back. I have both setups as well.

**Comment by [rushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/91378/rushik/) on 2022-01-15**:
I found the problem, but I am not sure how to fix it. The Windows implementation of the `getKey` function in [the python code](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_teleop/nodes/turtlebot3_teleop_key) is this:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
      if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
        return msvcrt.getch().decode()
      else:
        return msvcrt.getch()
```

The problem is that `getch()` is blocking. So, unless a key is pressed on the keyboard, the execution gets stuck inside `getKey` and the while loop on line 144 only publishes once per keypress.

The Linux implementation includes a 0.1 second timeout, the windows implementation does not. I tried

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-16**:
You could try to use `pyautogui` instead.

**Comment by [rushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/91378/rushik/) on 2022-01-16**:
Thanks for your help! I got it to work by changing a few things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this to work. The Windows implementation of the `getKey` function in [turtlebot3_teleop_key](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_teleop/nodes/turtlebot3_teleop_key) is this:

> ```
> if os.name == 'nt':
>     if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
>         return msvcrt.getch().decode()
>     else:
>         return msvcrt.getch()
> ```

The problem is that `getch()` is blocking. So, unless a key is pressed on the keyboard, the execution gets stuck inside `getKey` and the node only publishes one message per keypress instead of one message every 0.1 second like the Linux implementation. The Linux implementation includes a 0.1 second timeout, the windows implementation does not. I added a timeout using:

> ```
> if os.name == 'nt':
>     timeout = 0.1
>     startTime = time.time()
>     while(1):
>         if msvcrt.kbhit():
>             if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
>                 return msvcrt.getch().decode()
>             else:
>                 return msvcrt.getch()
>         elif time.time() - startTime > timeout:
>             return ''
> ```

That works for the most part, but `rosnode init` interfears with `SIGINT` so, we cannot stop the node using `Ctrl + c` anymore. To fix that, I had to change the `while(1)` on line 144 of the original file to `while not rospy_is_shutdown`. Now everything works as expected. See [this pull request](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/pull/815).

---

Originally posted by [rushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/91378/rushik/) with karma: 31 on 2022-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-16**:
Great job! Thank you for documenting response